# returning index array objective c

Tags: objective-c, arrays, return-value

Does anyone know a quick way to return the index of my array in a simple function something like this

```
  if([appDelegate.exerciseReference containsObject:aExerciseRef.IDE])
  {
      //return indexofwhere the object is the same ....  
  }
```

so let's say these two are the same at the index:5 from my array it would return a 5 integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSArray`'s [`indexOfObjectIndenticalTo:`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:) method:

```
if([appDelegate.exerciseReference containsObject:aExerciseRef.IDE])
{
    return [appDelegate.exerciseReference indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:aExerciseRef.IDE];
}
```

It returns an `NSUInteger` (a typedef for an `int` or `long` for 32-bit or 64-bit applications respectively) of the lowest index where the object is located.

Comment: Super though indexOfObject works the other one indexOfObjectIdenticalTo didn't ;)